# Logic App Standard (single tenant) - How to create additional/new workflow in existing logic app using REST API

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I have and existing Logic App Standard with a few workflows. The goal is to create additional workflows using REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To create a new workflow in your standard logic app.** You can change the kind to Stateless or Stateful as per your requirement and update the trigger/action/output in the request body as per your requirement.

**POST**
[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7Bsubscription) ID}/resourceGroups/{resource group name}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{logic app name}/deployWorkflowArtifacts?api-version=2018-11-01
Authorization: Bearer

**Request Body:**
{"files":{"<>/workflow.json":{"definition":{"$schema":[https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#,"actions":{},"contentVersion":"1.0.0.0","outputs":{},"triggers":{"manual":{"inputs":{},"kind":"Http","type":"Request"}}},"kind":"Stateful"}}}](https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#,%22actions%22:%7B%7D,%22contentVersion%22:%221.0.0.0%22,%22outputs%22:%7B%7D,%22triggers%22:%7B%22manual%22:%7B%22inputs%22:%7B%7D,%22kind%22:%22Http%22,%22type%22:%22Request%22%7D%7D%7D,%22kind%22:%22Stateful%22%7D%7D%7D)

**To Update the existing workflow in standard logic app**

**POST**
[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7Bsubscription) ID}/resourceGroups/{resource group name}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{logic app name}/hostruntime/runtime/webhooks/workflow/api/management/workflows/{yourworkflowname}/validate?api-version=2018-11-01
Authorization: Bearer

**Request Body:**
{"properties":{"definition":{"$schema":[https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#,"actions":{},"contentVersion":"1.0.0.0","outputs":{},"triggers":{"manual":{"inputs":{},"kind":"Http","type":"Request"}}},"kind":"Stateful"}}](https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#,%22actions%22:%7B%7D,%22contentVersion%22:%221.0.0.0%22,%22outputs%22:%7B%7D,%22triggers%22:%7B%22manual%22:%7B%22inputs%22:%7B%7D,%22kind%22:%22Http%22,%22type%22:%22Request%22%7D%7D%7D,%22kind%22:%22Stateful%22%7D%7D)

The standard logic app is built on top of the azure function app runtime, and it uses the same REST API as azure function. Make sure to add **Content-Type as application/json** in the header
To get familiar with function REST API you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps). To get familiar with Azure Management API and generating token refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/).

Comment: Strange this gives me an OK Status code 200 but I still see no workflow in my logic app. I also copied the same request body of an existing one but still I do not see it in the list of workflows.

Answer (score 0):

To Update the existing workflow in the standard logic app

After thorough investigation, I was able to find a clue to UPDATE & DELETE with Standard LogicApp; it's the same URL and payload as those for CREATE but with an additional Header value: If-Match : *